# What is client side loadbalancing

Tags: web-applications, server, load-balancing

I have searched enough in Google and haven't still understood what Client side loadbalancing is. Can someone explain what is client side loadbalancing and how is it different from server side load balancing

Answer (score 2):

In Client side load-balancing, load-balancing decision making is pushed to clients. In conventional manners, there should be a device sitting between clients and webserver. This device keep monitoring the servers load and make decision based on various parameter to which server client request should be forwarded to. But, in client side load-balancing, a small software sitting in client machine monitors the response from various source (mirror sites) and connect to the site which has provided better experience in the past.